# NameError when trying to run simple ruby commands from irb

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, cocoapods, nameerror

Anyone know why I would get this error: " NameError: undefined local variable or method `list' for main:Object
    from (irb):1"

anytime i try to run a ruby command such as "gem list" from irb? 
excuse my ignorance , ik nothing about Ruby and all im trying to do is install cocoapods to use with my ios projects.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `gem list` is not "ruby command". It's shell command to list all ruby gems installed on your machine. You should use this outside ruby's `irb` console.

Comment: alright but then why when i type the instructed command for installing cocoapods aka "gem install cocoapods" does the terminal just go to the next line and pop me into ruby instead of bash?

Comment: @ChuckKelly, Marek Lipka answered your question. You are to run terminal commands such as `gem install cocoapods` and `gem list` in a terminal. Not in IRB or a Rails console.